# Threejs - how much do you gain from using buffergeometries?

Tags: javascript, optimization, three.js

So I'm pretty much fine using either BufferGeometry or Geometry, I'm used to both at this point. I'm even used to using BufferGeometry in places where I have to modify things a lot - the code is more verbose, but not too much so.

So are there any guidelines that can be given on when to use which?

Comment: As with every optimization question the only reliable resource is benchmarking your specific use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the loaders in three.js are being modified to return `BufferGeometry` instead of `Geometry`. This is because the loading is faster, and `BufferGeometry` is more memory efficient.

`BufferGeometry` stores the data in a format that is easy to pass to the GPU. `Geometry` stores the data in a format that, in some regards, is more user-friendly. `Geometry`can be more convenient if you need to manipulate the geometry programatically.

three.js provides methods to convert between `Geometry` and `BufferGeometry`, so you can use either.

How much you gain in speed, or save in reduced memory usage, is use-case-specific.

Become familiar with both data structures, and you will be able to decide for yourself which one is best for your application.

three.js r.75

Comment: Thanks - but can I ask how much faster is BufferGeometry passed to the GPU? Or is that too dependent on other things to say?

Comment: `Geometry` is always converted to `BufferGeometry` by the renderer for passing to the GPU. The savings occurs on the CPU side if you can avoid creating `Geometry` altogether.

Comment: Thanks! And it does that conversion every frame? With a significant footprint?

Comment: No. Only once, prior to rendering.

Comment: Thanks again, but if the conversion happens only once (or is it every time you change something?) then why would buffer ever be faster? Sorry to be so insistent!

Comment: As I said in my answer, it is the loading of models from a file that is faster if the loader instantiates `BufferGeometry` instead of `Geometry`.

Comment: Right. Ok! Sorry to be thick!